# How to get a number of amount of addresses per day per month

Tags: mysql, sql, count, timestamp, datediff

I got a database where all data from a wifi sensor goes. Every mobile divice pings a "address" so every mobile divece sends alot of addresses per day what I now want is to see from every address how many times it came for example in the month April, March so I want to see from every "address" how many times a month it came (dont verget you cant just count it because you get alot of addresses per day and I need to count all the addresses per day as 1 not as 10 if there are 10 address on 14 April for example).

[Database I use](https://gyazo.com/cc160d7f4e63a3d3241cbbd1e443e439)

What I want

```
Address   |  Times
---------------------
adf9edb6GK| 2 times
adf9edb2933| 4 times
qwertdb2933| 1 times
```

What I tried is this:

> select address,
>          from_unixtime((sensordata1.time), '%Y-%m-%d') as datum,
>          count(distinct floor(time) / (24*60*60)) as Aantal_keer_per_maand from sensordata1 Where
>   (FROM_UnixTime((sensordata1.time), '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN #startDate# AND #endDate#) group by address,datum;

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `count(distinct)`:

```
select address,
       count(distinct floor(time) / (24*60*60)) as numDays
from t
group by address;
```

Comment: That is the amount of address per day what I need to know is how many time it is per month. And the amount per day needs to be counted as 1 not as the amount of addresses

Comment: @thattom . . . No.  This query is the number of days per month, not the address per day.

Comment: @Gordon_Linoff But I need to count 20address on a day as 1 not as the amout itself because now I got some with a value of 134 or higher what is impossible for a month with 30 days.

Comment: @thattom . . . You need a `where` clause to specify the month.

Comment: this is what I got but it still keeps giving me high numbers back :
 select address,
       from_unixtime((sensordata1.time), '%Y-%m-%d') as datum,
       count(distinct floor(time) / (24*60*60)) as Aantalkeer
from sensordata1
Where (FROM_UnixTime((sensordata1.time), '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN #startDate# AND #endDate#)
group by datum,address;

Comment: @thattom . . . Does the query in the answer have `datum` in the `group by`?

Comment: The problem is that I get numbers like 135and that is not possible. the code I use atm is this :: select address, from_unixtime((sensordata1.time), '%Y-%m-%d') as datum, count(distinct floor(time) / (24*60*60)) as Aantal_keer_per_maand from sensordata1 Where (FROM_UnixTime((sensordata1.time), '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN #startDate# AND #endDate#) group by address,datum;

But this is not correct

Comment: can you help me?